# Interfacing Python with Fortran module by ctypes

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I have this module in Fortran:

```
  MODULE utils
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PUBLIC
  INTEGER :: num_atom ! number of atoms in one configuration
    CONTAINS
      SUBROUTINE readin
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER :: iargc, ndim, i

     END SUBROUTINE readin

     SUBROUTINE convert
     IMPLICIT NONE
     REAL :: x,y,z
     END SUBROUTINE convert
```

I compile it by:

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC -cpp -O2 thiscode.f90 -o somelib.so
```

So, while trying to call the function "readin" from the following python code:

```
import os
_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/" + "somelib.so"

from ctypes import cdll, byref, c_int, c_double, c_char
lib_polint = cdll.LoadLibrary(_path)

def A():
    a = lib_polint.readin_

A()
```

I can not identify the name of the function into "somelib.so" and the following error appear:

"undefined symbol: readin_".

If I remove the module and keep just the subroutine "readin", it works. 
How to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Fortran interoperability with C to set the linker symbols to be anything you want

```
 SUBROUTINE readin bind(C, name="readin")
  INTEGER :: iargc, ndim, i

 END SUBROUTINE readin
```

Now the name of the subroutine as an externally visible C function will be just `readin` and you don't have to worry about the name mangling.

Without modules, you can sort of bet the name is `_readin` but it can also be `readin_` or `_readin_`, but not that often.

With modules it is a lottery, the name mangling really differs between compilers. No point using thos `_MOD_` symbols.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning to not forget the parentheses  in the case of a function, otherwise the code will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the symbols from the shared library

```
$ nm -D somelib.so
0000000000201020 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000201020 D _edata
0000000000201028 B _end
00000000000006f4 T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000005a0 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000000000006e0 T __utils_MOD_convert
0000000000201024 B __utils_MOD_num_at
00000000000006f0 T __utils_MOD_readin
```

Looks like having your subroutine in a module affected the symbol name. Instead of `readin_` you have `__utils_MOD_readin`. If you remove the surrounding module and leave your subroutines at the top level then you'll get the symbol names you expected.

For the record, I'm just reporting what I see on my system. I'm not familiar with fortran and don't know whether you can depend on this naming across compilers.